# flex builder 4 step by step tutorials how to use it?

Tags: apache-flex, flexbuilder

i am new to flex and need to learn how to use the flex builder 4 IDE is there a step by step tutorial to learn

2ndly i need to know about the following:

event model
validation cycle
display list
List-based controls, item renderers, AdvancedDataGrid, list interfaces

thanx in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adobe's Developer Connection website offers many tutorials that cover your requirements. Also Adobe Manuals are helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Read http://blog.flexexamples.com/ & Google & ADC like Jase suggested.